# Detectron MetadaCatalog and DatasetCatalog import Failed

Tags: python, linux, google-colaboratory, detectron

I'm trying the include of **Detectron2.data on Google Colab.** I made the connection for colab & my drive. And after that:

```
!pip install pyyaml
!pip install detectron2 -f https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/detectron2/wheels/cu101/torch1.7/index.html
```

It worked without any error.

i have been trying this;

```
import numpy as np
import os, json, cv2, random
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow


import detectron2
from detectron2.data import MetadataCatalog, DatasetCatalog
from detectron2.utils.visualizer import Visualizer
from detectron2 import model_zoo
```

But the outputs like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjLKL.png)

How can i fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed like this:

```
!pip install pyyaml==5.1
import torch, torchvision
print(torch.__version__, torch.cuda.is_available())
!gcc --version


import torch
assert torch.__version__.startswith("1.8")   
!pip install detectron2 -f https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/detectron2/wheels/cu101/torch1.8/index.html
# exit(0)  # After installation, you need to "restart runtime" in Colab. This line can also restart runtime
```

from: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/16jcaJoc6bCFAQ96jDe2HwtXj7BMD_-m5#scrollTo=ZyAvNCJMmvFF